OMNeT++ ver. 6.1 and matplotlib
I don't have (and don't want to have) a separate Python installation, but I have matplotlib version 3.5.2 (and I used it with omnet++ 6.0.3). Meanwhile, omnet++ 6.1 requests matplotlib version 3.5.3. How can I install it?
I tried to modify install.sh - with no effect.

The actual python module dependencies are described in the python/requirements.txt file. You can reduce the requirement to 3.5.2 there was a visual bug fix in 3.5.3 that we deemed to important, but you can just use the 3.5.2 fine.
BTW: the install.sh script does create a separate python virtual environment in the omnetpp_root/.venv directory, so in fact you have a separate installation
